# unexpected T_STRING syntax error

Tags: php

I have edited this line of code:

```
    $orderNumber            = $this->session->data['order_id'];
```

to become this line of code:

```
    $orderNumber            = ('ABC' . $this->session->data['order_id']);
```

and I am getting this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /xxx.php on line n

Looks fine to me but I must be missing something obvious...

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think `line n` is a number.. Post a few lines before your error line

Comment: Why have you added the barckets?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that line. You probably have a missing `;` on the *previous line* or so.

Comment: Or a prior string value that's not terminated.

Comment: Line is OKAY and you don't need () for string to be concatenated

Comment: if you can't find WHAT is causing the problem, don't presume that you can identify where the problem IS. show us more code, at least the whole function where this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also append to a variable using `.=`

```
$orderNumber = 'ABC';
$orderNumber .= $this->session->data['order_id'];
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. That seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I think that something like 
`$orderNumber            = 'ABC' . $this->session->data['order_id'];` must work for you. You don't need the brackets.

Comment: +1 for correct observation, -1 for not solving the problem. This particular error does not occur because of superfluous parentheses.

Comment: You're right, I just couldn't find anything else wrong in this line.